# How would you write this code using Functional programming

Tags: oop, functional-programming

I am learning Object Oriented and Functional programming. I found this very good and brief example (if you know better example, please suggest) on youtube explaining the OOP in 10 minutes, yay!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c4nP7GLL1c

Now, I would like to learn how to write this code in a Functional way - with immutability, recursion no loops etc.

```
DEMO.PHP
<?php
Include_once(“player.php”);

$p1 = new player();
$p1->name = “Brutus”;
$p1->type = “Warrior”;
$p1->hitpoints = 100;

$p2 = new player();
$p2->name = “Mysterio”;
$p2->type = “Sorcerer”;
$p2->hitpoints = 100;

$p1->meleeAttack($p2);
$p2->meleeAttack($p1);

Echo “<h1> Fight Results</h1>”;
Echo “<h2>.$p1->name.” now has “.$p1->hitpoints.” hit points</h2>”;
Echo “<h2>.$p2->name.” now has “.$p2->hitpoints.” hit points</h2>”;
?>


PLAYER.PHP
<?php
Class player {

    public $name;
    public $type;
    public $hitpoints;
    public function meleeAttack($target){
        $current_hp = $target->hitpoints;   // hp is for hitpoints
        $damage = rand(10,20);
        if($this->type == “Warrior”) {      // condition logic
            $damage += 10;
        }
        $target->hitpoints = $current_hp - $damage;
    }
}

?>
```

Cheers,
P.S. I know, PHP is not a language of choice for functional programming, no need to remind it :)

Comment: It's not going to be terribly different; you have no loops to replace. Basically, you make `meleeAttack` a function that takes two players as arguments and returns a new Player with reduced hit points, instead of a method that mutates a player. How you handle the random damage will vary, depending on whether you are using a pure functional language or not.

Comment: I dont understand, "...returns a new Player with ..." part. What happens to an old Player? how does the program know which Player is most recent? I need to see the code :(

Comment: Instead of updating a wrapped attribute, you replace the existing player with a new object that is identical, except it has fewer hit points. `meleeAttack` becomes something like a copy constructor, except the "copy" it makes is slightly different from the original (specifically, it has fewer hit points). If player 1 attacks player 2, you would write something like `$p2 = meleeAttack($p1, $p2)`. The function takes the attacker and its target as arguments, and returns a modified copy of the target.

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain how to do functional programming using [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) because I don't know PHP:

```hs
import System.Random (randomRIO)

-- Data Declarations

data Class = Warrior | Sorcerer deriving Eq

data Player = Player { name      :: String
                     , archetype :: Class
                     , hitpoints :: Int
                     }

-- Example Data

p1 :: Player
p1 = Player "Brutus" Warrior 100

p2 :: Player
p2 = Player "Mysterio" Sorcerer 100

-- Code Section

meleeAttack :: Player -> Player -> IO Player
source `meleeAttack` target = do
    damage <- randomRIO (10, 20)
    let bonus = if archetype source == Warrior then 10 else 0
    let newHP = hitpoints target - damage - bonus
    return target { hitpoints = newHP }

-- Main Function

main :: IO ()
main = do
    p2 <- p1 `meleeAttack` p2
    p1 <- p2 `meleeAttack` p1
    putStrLn "Fight Results"
    putStrLn (name p1 ++ " now has " ++ show (hitpoints p1) ++ " hitpoints")
    putStrLn (name p2 ++ " now has " ++ show (hitpoints p2) ++ " hitpoints")
```

Alright, so one of the biggest differences between object oriented programming and functional programming is separation of code and data:

1. In object oriented programming code and data are not kept separate. Just look at your own `Player` class. It has three public fields and a public method that operates on those fields.
2. In functional programming code and data are kept separate. Our data declarations are at the beginning of the program and the functions operating on that data come afterwards.

Another big difference is mutability. In object oriented programming, objects are usually mutable. Hence, methods usually modify an existing object. In functional programming mutation is considered bad. Hence, functions usually never modify anything. Instead, they return an updated copy of whatever data they were manipulating.

For example, consider the `meleeAttack` function. It takes two inputs, `source` and `target`, which are both `Player` data. The output is also `Player` data. It's the updated `target`. The original `target` is left unmodified.

Anyway, if you want to learn functional programming then you should read [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: Can this Haskel code be written in OOP way using class, objects properties, and methods? My apologies, I am learning and I would like to see a comparison between OOP and func.

Comment: You don't *have* objects in the OOP sense in functional programming. The `Player` data type encapsulates the state that your PHP class tracks, but instead of methods that update an given object, you write functions that return *new* objects that reflect a change to the function's argument.